# Isolation Forest Parameter tuning with gridSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science

I have multi variate time series data, want to detect the anomalies with isolation forest algorithm.
want to get best parameters from gridSearchCV, here is the code snippet of gridSearch CV.

input data set loaded with below snippet.

```
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
df.drop(['dataTimestamp','Anomaly'], inplace=True, axis=1)
X_train = df
y_train = df1[['Anomaly']] ( Anomaly column is labelled data).
```

define the parameters for Isolation Forest.

```
clf = IsolationForest(random_state=47, behaviour='new', score="accuracy")
param_grid = {'n_estimators': list(range(100, 800, 5)), 'max_samples': list(range(100, 500, 5)), 'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 'max_features': [5,10,15], 'bootstrap': [True, False], 'n_jobs': [5, 10, 20, 30]}

f1sc = make_scorer(f1_score)
grid_dt_estimator = model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid,scoring=f1sc, refit=True,cv=10, return_train_score=True)
grid_dt_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

after executing the fit , got the below error.

> ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.

Can some one guide me what is this about, tried average='weight', but still no luck, anything am doing wrong here.
please let me know how to get F-score as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You incur in this error because you didn't set the parameter `average` when transforming the f1_score into a scorer. In fact, as detailed in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html):

> average : string, [None, ‘binary’ (default), ‘micro’, ‘macro’,
>   ‘samples’, ‘weighted’] This parameter is required for
>   multiclass/multilabel targets. If None, the scores for each class are
>   returned.

The consequence is that the scorer returns multiple scores for each class in your classification problem, instead of a single measure. The solution is to declare one of the possible values of the `average` parameter for `f1_score`, depending on your needs. I therefore refactored the code you provided as an example in order to provide a possible solution to your problem:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, f1_score
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=500, 
                                       n_classes=2)

clf = IsolationForest(random_state=47, behaviour='new')

param_grid = {'n_estimators': list(range(100, 800, 5)), 
              'max_samples': list(range(100, 500, 5)), 
              'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 
              'max_features': [5,10,15], 
              'bootstrap': [True, False], 
              'n_jobs': [5, 10, 20, 30]}

f1sc = make_scorer(f1_score(average='micro'))

grid_dt_estimator = model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, 
                                                 param_grid,
                                                 scoring=f1sc, 
                                                 refit=True,
                                                 cv=10, 
                                                 return_train_score=True)
grid_dt_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Hi Luca, Thanks a lot your response. got the below error after modified the code f1sc = make_scorer(f1_score(average='micro')) , the error message is as follows     (TypeError: f1_score() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred').

Comment: issue has been resolved after label the data with 1 and -1 instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: I get the same error even after changing it to -1 and 1                  
 Counter({-1: 250, 1: 250})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: f1_score() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'

Comment: What will be the `scoring` parameter for unsupervised case of `IsolationForest`?

Answer (score 3):

Update make_scorer with this to get it working.

```
make_scorer(f1_score, average='micro')
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this, I have tried your solution but It does not work. My data is not labeled.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186702/using-gridsearchcv-with-isolationforest-for-finding-outliers

Answer (score 1):

Parameters you tune are not all **necessary**.
For example:
`contamination` is the rate for abnomaly, you can determin the best value after you fitted a model by tune the threshold on `model.score_samples`

`n_jobs` is the CPU core you used.