# Using GridSearchCV with IsolationForest for finding outliers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use `IsolationForest` for finding outliers. I want to find the best parameters for model with `GridSearchCV`. The problem is that I always get the same error:

```
TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator IsolationForest(behaviour='old', bootstrap=False, contamination='legacy',
                max_features=1.0, max_samples='auto', n_estimators=100,
                n_jobs=None, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False) does not.
```

It seems like its a problem because `IsolationForest` does not have `score` method.
Is there a way to fix this?
Also is there a way to find a score for isolation forest?
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

df = pd.DataFrame({'first': [-112,0,1,28,5,6,3,5,4,2,7,5,1,3,2,2,5,2,42,84,13,43,13],
                   'second': [42,1,2,85,2,4,6,8,3,5,7,3,64,1,4,1,2,4,13,1,0,40,9],
                   'third': [3,4,7,74,3,8,2,4,7,1,53,6,5,5,59,0,5,12,65,4,3,4,11],
                   'result': [5,2,3,0.04,3,4,3,125,6,6,0.8,9,1,4,59,12,1,4,0,8,5,4,1]})

x = df.iloc[:,:-1]

tuned = {'n_estimators':[70,80,100,120,150,200], 'max_samples':['auto', 1,3,5,7,10],
         'contamination':['legacy', 'outo'], 'max_features':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,15],
         'bootstrap':[True,False], 'n_jobs':[None,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,15,20,25,30], 'behaviour':['old', 'new'],
         'random_state':[None,1,5,10,42], 'verbose':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'warm_start':[True,False]}

isolation_forest = GridSearchCV(IsolationForest(), tuned)

model = isolation_forest.fit(x)

list_of_val = [[1,35,3], [3,4,5], [1,4,66], [4,6,1], [135,5,0]]
df['outliers'] = model.predict(x)
df['outliers'] = df['outliers'].map({-1: 'outlier', 1: 'good'})

print(model.best_params_)
print(df)
```

Comment: What would be *your* choice for a score? Accuracy? MSE? Also, please remove all code that comes *after* the reported error (it is never executed, hence irrelevant to the question - it just creates unnecessary clutter).

Comment: I want accuracy score, I have removed code irrelevant to the question

Comment: great question, @taga. Would it be hard to explain the use for a variable `list_of_val`? I did not find it being used in code anywhere, and would remove it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to create your own scoring function since `IsolationForest` does not have `score` method inbuilt. Instead you can make use of the `score_samples` function that is available in `IsolationForest` (can be considered as a proxy for `score`) and create your own scorer as described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) and pass it to the `GridSearchCV`. I have modified your code to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

df = pd.DataFrame({'first': [-112,0,1,28,5,6,3,5,4,2,7,5,1,3,2,2,5,2,42,84,13,43,13],
                   'second': [42,1,2,85,2,4,6,8,3,5,7,3,64,1,4,1,2,4,13,1,0,40,9],
                   'third': [3,4,7,74,3,8,2,4,7,1,53,6,5,5,59,0,5,12,65,4,3,4,11],
                   'result': [5,2,3,0.04,3,4,3,125,6,6,0.8,9,1,4,59,12,1,4,0,8,5,4,1]})

x = df.iloc[:,:-1]

tuned = {'n_estimators':[70,80], 'max_samples':['auto'],
     'contamination':['legacy'], 'max_features':[1],
     'bootstrap':[True], 'n_jobs':[None,1,2], 'behaviour':['old'],
     'random_state':[None,1,], 'verbose':[0,1,2], 'warm_start':[True]}  

def scorer_f(estimator, X):   #your own scorer
      return np.mean(estimator.score_samples(X))

#or you could use a lambda aexpression as shown below
#scorer = lambda est, data: np.mean(est.score_samples(data)) 

isolation_forest = GridSearchCV(IsolationForest(), tuned, scoring=scorer_f)
model = isolation_forest.fit(x)
```

> SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
print(model.best_params_)

{'behaviour': 'old',
 'bootstrap': True,
 'contamination': 'legacy',
 'max_features': 1,
 'max_samples': 'auto',
 'n_estimators': 70,
 'n_jobs': None,
 'random_state': None,
 'verbose': 1,
 'warm_start': True}
```

Comment: And is there a way to do this without `lambda`?

Comment: you could replace the `lambda` expression with a function as shown above.

Comment: Thanks my friend, can you please help me with this question ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214457/outlier-prediction-with-categorical-data-in-pythons-scikit-learn-lib

Answer (score -1):

I believe the scoring is referring to the GridSearchCV object, and not the IsolationForest.

If it is "None" (default) it will try to use the estimators scoring, which as you state does not exist. Try using one of the [available scoring metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) suitable to your problem within the GridSearchCV object

Comment: could you post the code showing this? Your current solution does not have this

Comment: The problem is that I think that Isolation Forest is unsupervised, so there is no way to put y_true and y_pred