# Evaluate multiple Isolation Forest estimators during GridSearchCV with custom scorer function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers, isolation-forest

I have a sample of values that don't have a y *target* value. Actually, the *X features* (predictors) are all used to fit the *Isolation Forest* estimator. The goal is to identify which of those X-features and the ones to come in the future are actually outliers. So for example let's say that I fit an array (340,3) => *(n_samples, n_features)* and I predict those features to identify which of the 340 observations are *outliers*.

My approach so far is:

First I create a pipeline object

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

steps=[('IsolationForest', IsolationForest(n_jobs=-1, random_state=123))]
pipeline=Pipeline(steps)
```

Then I create a parameters grid for the hyperparameter tuning

```py
parameteres_grid={'IsolationForest__n_estimators':[25,50,75],
                  'IsolationForest__max_samples':[0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0],
                  'IsolationForest__contamination':[0.01,0.05],
                  'IsolationForest__bootstrap':[True, False]
                 }
```

Finally, I apply the *GridSearchCV* algorithm

```
isolation_forest_grid=GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameteres_grid, scoring=scorer_f, cv=3, verbose=2)
isolation_forest_grid.fit(scaled_x_features.values)
```

My goal is to identify the best fit for a scoring function (noted as **scorer_f** that would efficiently select the most suitable isolation forest estimator for outlier detection.

So far, and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58236323/10623444) excellent answer, my scorer is as follows:

##### Scorer Function

```py
def scorer_f(estimator, X):
  thresh=np.quantile(estimator.score_samples(X), 0.05)
  scores=estimator.score_samples(X)
  return len(np.where(scores<thresh)[0])
```

A brief explanation, I identify constantly the 5% (0.05 quantile) of observations in the batch as outliers. Thus, every score less than the threshold is denoted as an outlier. As a result I instruct the GridSearch function to select the model with the most outliers as a worst-case scenario.

To give you a taste from the results:

```
isolation_forest_grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']

array([4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. ,
       4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 3.8, 4. ,
       4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 3.8, 4. , 4. ,
       4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. ])
```

The GridSearch function randomly selects the model on index 31 as the best model. As you can see most of the model estimators have 4.0 outliers, thus I expect the rest of the selection is done randomly.

Overall, I would like to ask if this approach is valid
*(mathematically correct)* and can produce valid model estimators for outlier detection. The drawback of outlier detection algorithms is their lack of a scorer metric in *sklearn.metrics* library. That's why I struggled in finding a good score metric for the `GridSearchCV` method.

Comment: "Overall, I would like to ask if this approach is valid (mathematically correct) and can produce valid model estimators for outlier detection." is not a programming question, and so off-topic here.

Comment: @BenReiniger I would like to point that *mathematically* refers to the python code behind the mathematic representation of the scorer function.

Comment: Anyway, your scorer sets 5% of the data as outliers, with the only differing scores apparently coming from ties. I doubt that's a particularly useful metric.

Comment: @BenReiniger Do you know any other more useful metric that could help me better assess the model estimators during the GridSearch?

Comment: I do not; I have some ideas, but don't know if there are any established ones. That would make a good question over at stats.SE or datascience.SE.

Comment: @BenReiniger I posted the question on datascience.SE https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/111597/evaluate-multiple-isolation-forest-estimators-during-gridsearchcv-with-custom-sc

Comment: @BenReiniger If you are familiar with Python coding you can write your ideas and we will stretch them if any good one arises.

Comment: Any update on this issue?