# Can GridSearchCV be used for unsupervised learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, outliers, grid-search, isolation-forest

I am trying to build an outlier detector to find outliers in test data. That data varies a bit (more test channels, longer testing).

First im applying the train test split because i wanted to use grid search with train data to get the best results. This is timeseries data from multiple sensors and i removed the time column beforehand.

```
X shape : (25433, 17)
y shape : (25433, 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.33,
                                                    random_state=(0))
```

Standardize afterwards and then i changed them into an int Array because GridSearch doesnt seem to like continuous data. This surely can be done better, but i want this to work before i optimize the coding.

```
'X'
mean = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = mean.transform(X_train)
X_test = mean.transform(X_test)

X_train = np.round(X_train,2)*100
X_train = X_train.astype(int)
X_test = np.round(X_test,2)*100
X_test = X_test.astype(int)

'y'
yeah = StandardScaler().fit(y_train)
y_train = yeah.transform(y_train)
y_test = yeah.transform(y_test)
y_train = np.round(y_train,2)*100
y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_test = np.round(y_test,2)*100
y_test = y_test.astype(int)
```

I chose the IsoForrest because its fast, has pretty good results and can handle huge data sets (i currently only use a chunk of the data for testing).
SVM might also be an option i want to check out.
Then i set up the GridSearchCV

```
clf = IForest(random_state=47, behaviour='new',
              n_jobs=-1)

param_grid = {'n_estimators': [20,40,70,100], 
              'max_samples': [10,20,40,60], 
              'contamination': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001], 
              'max_features': [5,15,30], 
              'bootstrap': [True, False]}

fbeta = make_scorer(fbeta_score,
                    average = 'micro',
                    needs_proba=True,
                    beta=1)

grid_estimator = model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, 
                                              param_grid,
                                              scoring=fbeta,
                                              cv=5,
                                              n_jobs=-1,
                                              return_train_score=True,
                                              error_score='raise',
                                              verbose=3)

grid_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**The Problem:**

GridSearchCV needs an y argument, so i think this only works with supervised learning? If i run this i get the following error that i dont understand:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Comment: What is the type of `y_train` and the type of `clf.predict`? Are they compatible each other?

Comment: `y_train` is an 2D-Array of int32 and `clf.predict` is a method of the iForest. 
This definitely should work together as i already used the iForrest without GridSearchCV.

Comment: Okay. You should provide a reproducible example. Currently, the code is incomplete because it does not have `X` and `y` are not given and misses import lines.

Comment: We need a bit more information. You say you're doing unsupervised learning, but you have targets `y`, which are continuous. You try to use Fbeta, which is a (hard) classification metric, and you try to pass it probability scores.  What are you actually trying to accomplish, and how do you measure success?

Comment: Im not allowed to make the data public... ill try to provide as much info as possible. The Data it float, multimodal and has a range between -0,8 and 40.000.
I used the y target because GridSearch would thow an missing y_true label error at me. Thats why im asking if GridSearch can only be used for supervised learning.

Comment: Because i think GridSearch needs a target (y_true) i choose y to be a single column of the data (Battery State of Charge) and X represents the rest of the data. 


Im not against supervised learning, but i couldnt find a suitable algorithm to handle huge data with decent performance.

Why is it important to show where the data comes from when i just want to know if GridSearch is capable of supervised learning or not.

Comment: The sucess is measured by my f1_scorer and shown by an confusion matrix. If theres a good balance between precision and recall im happy

Comment: How can you measure f1 or precision or recall, or produce a confusion matrix, if you don't have an actual target? // You can use grid search for unsupervised learning, if you can provide a scoring metric; but so far you haven't provided one that will work with your data (as the error message attests). Just throwing a column into `y` is not a solution.

Comment: i didnt knew about the missing scoring function, thank you ! 
And the batery_soc is the most important value in my data because it should not leave a certain range. 
when i declare a fitting scoring function, how and where do i pass it ?

Comment: @BenReiniger i dont know how to build a scoring metric for this problem, do you have any advice or info that can help me to develop one ? 
Im sorry that this post may be confusing, im learning by myself and im obviously missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GridSearchCV` for unsupervised learning, but it's often tricky to define a scoring metric that makes sense for the problem.

[Here's an example in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_digits_kde_sampling.html) that uses grid search for `KernelDensity`, an unsupervised estimator. It works without issue because this estimator has a `score` method ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.score)).

In your case, since `IsolationForest` doesn't have a `score` method, you'll need to define a custom scorer to pass as the search's `scoring` method. There's an answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58186702/10495893), and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72487193/10495893), but I don't think the metrics given there necessarily makes sense. Unfortunately, I don't have a useful outlier detection metric in mind; that's a question better suited for the data science or statistics stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Ben Reiniger's answer and it  has good links for other SO posts on this topic.
You can try creating a custom scorer by assuming you can make use of  `y_train` . This is not strictly `unsupervised` .

Here is one example where R2 score  is used as a scoring metric.

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def scorer_f(estimator, X_train,Y_train):
  y_pred=estimator.predict(Xtrain)
  return r2_score(Y_train, y_pred)
```

Then you can use it as normal.

```
clf = IForest(random_state=47, behaviour='new',
              n_jobs=-1)

param_grid = {'n_estimators': [20,40,70,100], 
              'max_samples': [10,20,40,60], 
              'contamination': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001], 
              'max_features': [5,15,30], 
              'bootstrap': [True, False]}

grid_estimator = model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, 
                                              param_grid,
                                              scoring=scorer_f,
                                              cv=5,
                                              n_jobs=-1,
                                              return_train_score=True,
                                              error_score='raise',
                                              verbose=3)

grid_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```